# Apache JMeter : Add random data in body for request

Tags: java, random, jmeter, stress-testing

I'm working on stress testing our application in Apache JMeter.

I thought of calling register user method which will add users in the database. But if the email already exists, then the database action does not take place.

How can I add a random number in body data? Or is there some other way I can stress test my application connected with database?

Here are some screenshots :
[image][image]

Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    System.out.println("Person add called"+person.getUsername());
    person.setUsername(this.stripHTML(person.getUsername()));
    int personId = this.personService.addPerson(person);
    if (!(personId == 0)) {
        Person person1 = this.personService.getPersonById(personId);
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(person1, null, authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return "redirect:/canvaslisting";
    } else {
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Use [Random Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable) with variable name emailValue and send ${emailValue} in request
2. Use [JDBC request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) to your database to create random number or sequence and save in variable name emailValue
3. Use [UUID](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) function to create uniqueId  and send in email ${uniqueId}@gmail.com for example

Comment: AS your UUID worked out, I will use that. and create a new question for the current problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) like:

- [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - which generates a random number in the given range
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - which generates a random string from the given input
- [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) - which returns the current thread number
- [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) - which returns an unique GUID structure
- [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) - which returns current time stamp in different formats
- any combination of above

JMeter functions can be used anywhere in the test so you can put them directly into your request body.

Some more recommendations:

- Don't use JMeter GUI for running the load test, GUI mode is designed for tests development and debugging only, the tests themselves need to be run [in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- Remove all the listeners from the test plan while running your load test as [JMeter listeners are very resource intensive](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) and create unnecessary overhead.

Comment: this is very useful thanks

Answer (score 12):

My example with [__UUID](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID)

[image]

For POST request, make sure you have correct **Content-Type** in **HTTP Header Manger** , **application/json** for example.