# jmeter request and response codes

Tags: jmeter

request
GET https://issuemgr.snaponbusinesssolutions.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/xboard/issue/matchesBoard?rapidViewId=148&issueIdsOrKeys=GMQA-2734&_=1539077743079

respone
{"issueIdsOrKeys":["GMQA-2734"]}

while recording a script to create a task in jira i get the above request and respone.
what i need to do is every time the issueIdsOrKeys should be different so on every run a task is created.

Comment: If you want random string see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800557/apache-jmeter-add-random-data-in-body-for-request

Answer (score 0):

Looking into Jira [REST API examples](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/) when you create an issue you should get response like:

```
{
    "id":"39000",
    "key":"TEST-101",
    "self":"http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/39000"
}
```

So if your test is about creating a task and then verifying that it is in the dashboard - you need to extract this `key` attribute value using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor), the relevant [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be as simple as `$.key`